# How do erb-style templates work in marionette?

Tags: javascript, marionette, template-engine

In the documentation concerning Marionette.ItemView, you can find this template:

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/html">
  <ul>
    <% _.each(items, function(item){ %>
    <li> <%= item.someAttribute %> </li>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
</script>
```

To call this template into action, we use something like this:

```
var MyItemsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#some-template"
});
```

I use this kind of template and it works fine, but I don't understand how it works. Mostly, what I don't understand is how to reproduce the above without using a script tag. See my attempt below:

```
var MyItemsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: function (items) {
    return _.template("<ul><% _.each(items, function (item) { %><li><% item.someAttribute %></li><% }); %></ul>");
  }
});
```

Could someone explain how this works and where the `items` object comes from?

Comment: Have you read the [underscore template docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template)?

Comment: @steveax Yes I have. I just re-read them now, but they don't answer my question, nor do they elaborate on how they are used by Marionette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mostly, what I don't understand is how to reproduce the above without using a script tag.

The template is a string that Underscore knows how to parse into a function. If you want to move your templates out of script tags, you can move them into their own files and [precompile them](http://www.codebelt.com/javascript/precompiling-javascript-underscore-templates/) or if you're using Require.js, require them as a dependency using the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text).

> ... where the items object comes from?

From the Marionette [ItemView docs](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#rendering-a-collection-in-an-itemview):

> The important thing to note here, is the use of items as the variable
>   to iterate in the _.each call. This will always be the name of the
>   variable that contains your collection's items.